# What are the optimal tuning values for RHEL 5.3 Xen kernel on a Dell 2950?

Tags: linux, xen, performance-tuning, dell-poweredge

How to do Linux Tuning and Performance? any one has done for xen kernel ?

Comment: This is a hopelessly vague question. Try to formulate something more specific.

Comment: Agree with Geoff, -1.  Tempting to vote to close.

Comment: I have to agree... the question is too absolutely vague and ambiguous to even attempt to answer with any hope of solution steps.

Comment: Rajat, I don't like closing questions unless they belong on the other sites...but others will vote this closed unless you can reword it with more details - how much RAM, how many CPU cores to commit, what kind of workload, drive space available, etc.  If you don't reword it soon, enough votes will probably pile up and be cast on this question to close it.  I'd get to it quick in a few hours...

Comment: any way i got speed on my network around 200mbs thanks help all of u

Comment: what are the specs of the machine? This is a wildly vague question as of today ..

Answer (score 2):

You first have to figure out where your bottleneck is, i.e., disk IO.  Then figure out your usage patters and see if there is anything that might improve your situation.  The sysstat package which has sar and iostat is a good place to start to collect the information.

Chances are, the defaults are probably best :-)

Comment: what all defaults parameter to get best performance out dell 2950 with rhel 5.3 sen kernel?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the bottleneck
2. Speed up the bottleneck
3. Goto Step 1

If you just want a throwaway link [this article](http://timetobleed.com/useful-kernel-and-driver-performance-tweaks-for-your-linux-server/) on kernel and driver performance tweaks will sate your appetite.